# IsLoading not refreshed to newest value react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have a question regarding the usage of useMutate in react-query.

I have the following logic for post requests (currently it's using the mocked one)

```
const loginWithEmailAndPassword = async (
  params: LoginRequest
): Promise<AuthResponse> => {
  const payload = JSON.stringify(params);
  const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, payload);
  return response.data;
};

const mockLoginWithEmailAndPassword = async (
  params: LoginRequest
): Promise<AuthResponse> => {
  params;
  console.log(params);
  await delay(3);
  return {
    authToken: 'login_auth_token',
    refreshToken: 'login_auth_refresh_token',
    companyId: '1',
    role: 'company',
  };
};

const fn = selectBasedOnMock(
  mockLoginWithEmailAndPassword,
  loginWithEmailAndPassword
);

export const useLogin = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (params: LoginRequest) => fn(params),
  });
};
```

When i perform this mutation in the LoginForm component while clicking on login, the loginMutation.isSuccess property is set to 'false' even after the request is completed, and only after i press the button again, the isSuccess property is set to 'true' and the statements inside of it get executed

```
const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    const params = { email, password };
    await loginMutation.mutateAsync(params);

    if (loginMutation.isSuccess) {
      setCompanyId(loginMutation.data.companyId);
      storage.setToken(loginMutation.data.authToken);
      setUserRole(loginMutation.data.role);
    }
  };
```

What am i doing wrong here? How to ensure that i get the freshest value of isSuccess and perform the required updates?

This is how i initialize the mutation

```
const loginMutation = useLogin()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the docs, and particularly this resource:
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query

I found the solution:

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    const params = { email, password };
    loginMutation.mutate(params, {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setCompanyId(data.companyId);
        storage.setToken(data.authToken);
        setUserRole(data.role);
      },
    });
  };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).